# Want to loop through questions and count correct answers

Tags: android

I'd like to show a series of 10 questions and have the user answer, and have the app show whether the answer is correct, and then show the next question.

Right now I can show the first question, check whether it's correct, and then display the second question. I don't know how to get this looping, however, to show all questions. Here is the relevant code:

```
public class MathTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int i = 0;
int n = 20; /*How many rows this test*/
String[] mathTest = new String[40];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mathtest);

    final TextView mathProblem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mathProblem);
    final EditText mathAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mathAnswer);

    //Styling for the question text
    mathProblem.setTextSize(40);
    mathProblem.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));


    //Try to read the problem and answers text file
    try {
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mediummath);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;

        int n = 20; /*How many rows this test has*/
        /*read in file to array*/
        for (i = 0; i < n; i=i+2) {
            if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                mathTest[i] = line;
            if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                mathTest[i+1] = line;
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mathProblem.setText(mathTest[0]);

    Button enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterButton);
    enterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int correctcount = 0;
                i = 0;

                String answer = mathAnswer.toString() ;
                String correctAnswer = mathTest[i+1];


                    if (answer.equals(correctAnswer)){
                        Toast.makeText(MathTestActivity.this,
                                        R.string.correct_toast,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        correctcount++;
                        i = i + 2;
                        mathProblem.setText(mathTest[i]);
                        correctAnswer = mathTest[i+1];
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(MathTestActivity.this,
                                correctAnswer,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        i = i + 2;
                        mathProblem.setText(mathTest[i]);
                        correctAnswer = mathTest[i+1];
                    }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: When I said (question, answer) pairs in your previous question, I would have recommended making a simple `Question` class with two String fields.

Comment: Hm. That might be better. Is this something that could be done when the app is created? I was just thinking and whether it is the array I used or the Question class you suggested, both would take time to create if I do it each time I open the app.

Comment: What do you mean "when the app is created"? Do you know how to make a Java class? `public class Question { String text, answer; }`... That is literally it.

Comment: No, I understand that. I can create the class. What I mean by that is, at some point the questions will go from the text file to another form that I can use. My method uses an array, and your method uses a new class. My question is, should I transfer the contents of the text file when this MathTestActivity class is started like I did in my solution? This is part of an android app, so whenever a user clicks on this page it will read from the text file every time. This seems pointless to do every single time, so I was hoping to only do it once.I don't know how apps work tho. Am I making sense?

Comment: Ohh. I see. Yes, the file will be read everytime you start the Activity. If you would like that not to happen, then you'll need to use SQLite, probably, but that's a lot more work than just reading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't count the correct answers with a local variable that gets set to 0 each time you click the button. :)

You should move `int correctcount = 0;` outside of the listener and next to your `i` and `n` variables.

You will also want to remove the `i = 0;` line from inside the button click because that will reset you back to the first question every time you click the button.

Also, since these three lines are duplicated between the if and the else, you can just place them directly after the else.

```
i = i + 2;
mathProblem.setText(mathTest[i]);
correctAnswer = mathTest[i+1]; // this isn't needed, though
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting your questions in `ViewPager` if you want to make the questions shown in sliding presentation (http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Or you can put your question inside a `ListView` if you want to view the question from top to bottom. (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

**EDIT:**
Actually you are close to achieve what you want to do.

You should delete `i = 0;` inside your button onClick() function as it prevents you from going to next questions (3rd, 4th, etc). You might want to consider clearing the mathAnswer EditText when the user submits a question.

Also, it is not necessary to set `correctAnswer = mathTest[i+1];` inside your if-else function.

Comment: Is it possible to simply have the question appear on top of the page, and change after every answer is input? Neither of those options allow for that :/

Answer (score 0):

Use arraylist for questions array and answer array.use view pager with two layouts questions and answer layout.if the answer array of position equal to the user answer its correct answer like u can dynamically